# Photoshop scripting - access index of selected regions

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I have an image with lets say five separate regions selected at once. Is there a way thru scripting that  I can access the index value of these regions and loop thru them. Or either some type of forall call that I could do?

Comment: Can you select the regions individually and then record their co-ordinates and access them that way? Or do you get all teh selection info at once? Other than that, try Anna's idea. Else you could try putting the selection to a layer mask & then try to analyze the bitmap data to work out the selections (good luck with that one)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the selection to a path and then loop through the vertices in each path to get the boundary area.  It is slow if you've got a large/complicated selection though.